# Eclipse, Android can't see activity - Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am usually working on Android Studio so I am not familiar with Eclipse project composition that much. In general I've set my project and I am getting error log presented below. It seems very trivial at first sight because you would think "there is no activity in manifest or you have specified in wrong way". But I've spent already 3 hours fighting with this and I have no idea anymore where could be the mistake.

In general I've tried to rename activity from

```
kamil.krzyk.agh.eds.activity.MenuActivity
```

to for example:

```
.activity.MenuActivity
```

or just:

```
.MenuActivity
```

Cleaning project many times, rebuilding, restarting IDE, moving activity class to root, checked if in Project Properties -> Builder everything is checked. Status of Java Build Path is:
[image]

Code of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kamil.krzyk.agh.eds"
    android:versionCode="301"
    android:versionName="3.01" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="kamil.krzyk.agh.eds.activity.MenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My project tree looks like this:
[image]

And location of MenuActivity.class on my harddrive is:
[image]

Generally project compiles/builds and I can run it but instantly I get error. I've changed package of my project once. I can't see where is the mistake. Please take a look at it, give some suggestions, ideas, help me anyway you could. Thank you.

Error log:

```
09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308): Process: kamil.krzyk.agh.eds, PID: 32308
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{kamil.krzyk.agh.eds/kamil.krzyk.agh.eds.activity.MenuActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kamil.krzyk.agh.eds.activity.MenuActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kamil.krzyk.agh.eds-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kamil.krzyk.agh.eds-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kamil.krzyk.agh.eds.activity.MenuActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kamil.krzyk.agh.eds-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kamil.krzyk.agh.eds-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    ... 10 more
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kamil.krzyk.agh.eds.activity.MenuActivity
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):        ... 13 more
    09-27 22:52:27.120: E/AndroidRuntime(32308):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported for Android development, switch to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

From yours screenshots I guess that package kamil.krzyk.agh.eds (which has white color) isn't a source folder. So look at yours project settings.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738710/3212712) you should:

> right click on project and go to project properties, then goto java build path, and then in source tab, click on add folder button and add `kamil.krzyk.agh.eds' (or maybe you should add 'src' folder) folder.

Comment: I have checked the answer you gave to me. I had linked 'src' and 'gen' folders in my Java Build Path -> Source location. 'kamil.krzyk.agh.eds' are packages inside src folder so I can add again something that is already added because it displays that "I can't add nested folders". It seems if 'src' is added then everything inside too.

Comment: @F1sher, I'm sure that something wrong with yours `kamil.krzyk.agh.eds` package as it must not be white, but brown as others... Try to recreate it and fill with other packages and files