# Howto properly integrate Android SDK (Adt) and Maven :

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, adt, m2eclipse

I've created an android project based on android-release archetype (via mvn CLI).
In order to import it to eclipse ADT (version 21) I tried:

- mvn eclipse:eclipse

The problem with this approach was that the created eclipse project was a Java project and didn't have an 'android' nature.

so I tried:

- importing the pom.xml using M2E eclipse plugin (Maven Integration for Eclipse)

now I have 2 different problems:

- the gen folder is not the one used by maven, [and I have to add it as a source folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532045/gen-already-exists-but-is-not-a-source-folder).
- getting [ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974432/classnotfoundexception-when-running-junit-unit-tests-within-eclipse-using-maven) for the unit test classes when running via eclipse. Maven has no problems at all.

is this how it supposed to work ? am I doing here something wrong, or I simply have too high expectations?

Comment: Ohh and forgot to mention the annoying "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description" Error with the even more annoying workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/14634575/20065

Comment: Do not use maven-eclipse-plugin as it doesn't know how to generate project files for Android project properly. Use `File -> Import ... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects`import the mavenized Android project. Make sure you have m2e and m2e-android Eclipse plugins installed.