# Building project in Eclipse for Andriod (Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0)

Tags: android, eclipse

Have a problem with importing and building project using Eclipse.

I had imported project and when i'm trying to RUN it, i got a message below :
[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaHAh.jpg)

So i read about that and found here on Stackoveflow solution :

[Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117815/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead)

also here:

[Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013445/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-4)

SOLUTION :

```
Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
Project > propetries> set JDK version to 1.5 or 1.6
```

So i did that, and try again, but now i have a new problem 
[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gicik.jpg)

It says to me: : `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

So i read about that again and found that i should set JDK and JRE version - 1.8

But when i set JDK and JRE to 1.8 problem 1 came back)

So.. can you, guys maybe help me?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should not be using any JDK besides version 8.  All the others are well past the end of their support lives.  Upgrade your Android tools to match.  Compile and run version 8 bytecode.

Comment: eclipse did not support ADT tools from API level 23 or higher. so try to compile with 5.0

Comment: When i'm trying to compile with 5.0 - i get a message : com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0